# Python - scapy sniff() filter with port range

Tags: python, range, port, scapy, packet-sniffers

I want to sniff all packets in a range of ports with the scapy module.

This is how it works for one port..

```
from scapy.all import *
packets = sniff(filter='udp and port 14000')
```

But rather than only port 14000, i want to sniff the range from 14000 up to 64000.

The following code does not work..

```
from scapy.all import *
packets = sniff(filter='udp and port 14000 to 64000')
```

What should the filter string look like if I want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Scapy* uses the [*BPF* syntax](http://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html) for specifying the filter:

```
packets = sniff(filter='udp and portrange 14000-64000')
```

Note that the range is inclusive and that no spaces are allowed around the `'-'` sign.